# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: python, django

У меня возникает ошибка 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager', когда я захожу на страницу профиля пользователя на своем сайте. Используется кастомная модель пользователя:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True
    )
    phoneNumberRegex = RegexValidator(regex=r"^\+?1?\d{8,15}$")
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(
        validators=[phoneNumberRegex], max_length=16, unique=True, blank=True, null=True
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    subscribe = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="subscribes",
    )
    subscriber = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="subscribers",
    )
```

Код views для страниц пользователей:

```
class CustomUserListView(ListView):
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    template_name = "accounts/customuser_list.html"


class CustomUserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    template_name = "accounts/customuser_detail.html"
```

Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ion\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\ion\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\ion\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\ion\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\ion\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 154, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "E:\ion\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 34, in get_queryset
    queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
[09/Nov/2022 20:51:39] "GET /accounts/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78275
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связяно?
Пакеты:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cryptography==38.0.3
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==4.1.3
django-allauth==0.51.0
django-friendship==1.9.6
idna==3.4
oauthlib==3.2.2
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.6.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.6
urllib3==1.26.12
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А где именно ошибка? В вашем примере даже нет никаких упоминаний `_default_manager`. Скорее всего ошибка в другом месте. Представьте пожалуйста код `View` для страницы с ошибкой и traceback самой ошибки

Comment: @NEStenerusnester, когда я иду по пути просмотра списка пользователей и страниц отдельных пользователей, возникает эта ошибка. Самостоятельно я не использовал _default_manager и вообще слабо понимаю что это и для чего нужно. Добавил недостающие данные.

Comment: Замените `model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` на `model = CustomUser`. Ошибка из-за того, что в `AUTH_USER_MODEL` строка, а нужна именно django модель (стандартные реализации view типа ListView ожидают, что в поле model будет именно модель и обращаются к нему как к модели) . Тут нет смысла делать универсально, у вас view заточена под конкретно вашу модель.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, спасибо, помогло.